# How can I have dev/test/cert/prod environments in K8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for best option in handling DEV, TEST, CERT and PROD environments in Kubernetes.

Comment: Any research so far? Are there any more specific questions you have or do you have a problem with it?

Comment: One of the option mentioned in K8s documentation is namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use namespaces in Kubernetes. Create one namespace per environment.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/namespaces/

Once things get more involved, you can may be move to one cluster per environment, or something like DEV, TEST in a cluster and CERT and PROD in their own clusters.